# JAVA RMI arraylist update and return array

Tags: java

I am writing a program which display the content of database into a JTable,But the tricky part is that i gotta use RMI, i am having a little trouble passing the arraylist, modifying it on the server side and returning it updated. I will appreciate any help, please note that i am almost a complete beginner so i cant really figure out what i a doing wrong, i would really be happy to learn how to accomplish this if anyone is willing to help.

This is my interface implementation:

```
public ArrayList passArrayList(ArrayList empjobslist, String tempName) throws RemoteException {
    Statement st;
    ResultSet rs;
    String name = null;
    String surname = null;
    String finalUserName = null;
    String tempFinalUserName = null;
    ArrayList<empJobsList> a = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        String tempNametemp = tempName;
        // converting username into name and lastname to be displayed in
        // userLabel
        String userQuery = "SELECT NAME, LASTNAME FROM WAITERS WHERE USERNAME = '" + tempNametemp + "'";
        st = con.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery(userQuery);
        while (rs.next()) {
            name = rs.getString("NAME");
            surname = rs.getString("LASTNAME");
        }
        finalUserName = name + "" + surname;
        tempFinalUserName = finalUserName.toUpperCase();
        try {
            String displayQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + tempFinalUserName + "";
            st = con.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery(displayQuery);
            empJobsList empjoblist;
            while (rs.next()) {
                empjoblist = new empJobsList(rs.getString("role"), rs.getString("location"),
                        rs.getString("neareststation"), rs.getString("hourlyrate"), rs.getString("hours"),
                        rs.getString("date"));
                a.add(empjoblist);
            }
            System.out.println(empjobslist);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("something wrong");
    }
    return a;
}
```

And this is my client program

```
public ArrayList<empJobsList> getEmpJobsListList() {
    ArrayList<empJobsList> empjobslist = new ArrayList<>();
    String tempName = uNameLbl.getText();
    WaitersInterface display = null;
    try {
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(registryPort);
        WaitersInterface wii = (WaitersInterface) registry.lookup(registryName);
        System.out.println("Connected succesfully");
        try {
            System.out.println();
            wii.passArrayList(empjobslist, tempName);
            System.out.println("List after" + empjobslist);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    } catch (Exception es) {
    }
    return empjobslist;
}

public void display_jobs() {
    ArrayList<empJobsList> a = getEmpJobsListList();
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) empJobTable.getModel();
    Object[] row = new Object[6];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        row[0] = a.get(i).getrole();
        row[1] = a.get(i).getlocation();
        row[2] = a.get(i).getneareststation();
        row[3] = a.get(i).gethourlyrate();
        row[4] = a.get(i).gethours();
        row[5] = a.get(i).getdate();
        model.addRow(row);
    }
}
```

And this is my JobsList class

```
    public class JobsList {

    private String role, location, neareststation, hourlyrate, hours, date;

    public JobsList(String role, String location, String neareststation, String hourlyrate, String hours,
            String date) {
        this.role = role;
        this.location = location;
        this.neareststation = neareststation;
        this.hourlyrate = hourlyrate;
        this.hours = hours;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getrole() {
        return role;
    }

    public String getlocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public String getneareststation() {
        return neareststation;
    }

    public String gethourlyrate() {
        return hourlyrate;
    }

    public String gethours() {
        return hours;
    }

    public String getdate() {
        return date;
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
List after[]
Connected succesfully
```

Comment: Do you really have a table per username? It doesn't seem likely, but that's what your second SELECT statement requires. And when you catch an exception, don't just print out moronic messages like "something went wrong". Print out *what* went wrong, which is *in the exception.*

Comment: Yes i do have table per customer, i know its seem silly, it probably is, but hey i only started and this was the way i figured it out.

Comment: There is data inside the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wii.passArrayList(empjobslist, tempName);
```

This doesn't update the list. You are throwing away the return value. It should be:

```
empjobslist = wii.passArrayList(empjobslist, tempName);
```

So in fact passing the empty list as a parameter is pointless.

Comment: Hmm ok so how would you go around this problem? Anything in my code that is particular wrong?

Comment: **EH?** What on earth are you talking about? I've answered your question. I've pointed out the incorrect code. I've stated what's wrong with it. I've provided the correct code.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, just wasn’t sure if that was it. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes i have just corrected my code with yours and it works perfectly, i am really grateful.

Comment: I am unable to see what you could possibly have been unsure about. I expressed myself clearly. Baffling really.